# SpringMVC integration with FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm working through online examples to learn SpringMVC with FreeMarker. I came accross with this error, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my getFreemarkerConfig() method and all day I've been trying to fix it, bu unsuccessfully nothing done.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.capfer")
public class Webconfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver frViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        frViewResolver.setCache(false);
        // frViewResolver.setPrefix("");
        frViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");

        return frViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
        factory.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        factory.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setConfiguration(factory.createConfiguration());
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
}


SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getFreemarkerConfig' defined in com.capfer.configuration.Webconfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer]: Factory method 'getFreemarkerConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Lfreemarker/template/Version;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer]: Factory method 'getFreemarkerConfig' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Lfreemarker/template/Version;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Please, any idea how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root error is this: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.(Lfreemarker/template/Version;)V". This means that you have an old FreeMarker dependency, where there was no `Configuration(Version)` constructor yet. So ensure that you are using the latest FreeMarker version (`2.3.26-incubating` is the latest stable release as of this writing). (If the old version is a transitive dependency, you need to exclude it, so that it won't win again later as the dependency graph changes.)